# One-To-One reference side

Tags: sql

I'm not sure if I named this question right.

Imagine that there is two tables: one that represents Users and another represents Addresses.
One user can have only one address:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    full_name VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Address (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    address_line_1 VARCHAR(255),
    address_line_2 VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

The question is: where is the right place to put foreign key reference to? Should I put a reference column into the User table by creating "address_id" column that references to Address.id? Or should I put user_id column into the Address table that references to User.id?

Comment: You should be asking yourself "Do the User object reference to it's Address or does the Address reference to it's User".

Comment: *One user can have only one address* what about the adress? in which direction(s) you want to mavigate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have 1-1 association, you need to ask yourself why is it there in the first place? Most of the times it indicate that the design is incomplete or inaccurate. Sometimes 1-1 is correct, don't get me wrong, but you have to justify its existence.

Having said that,in your case, chances are you will be accessing the user as the main table. Your end-users may be looking for user profiles by userid,then drill down or navigate to more profile information such as the address. If this is the case, the FK would belong to the address table. However, if your business is such that your end-user will be browsing address information primarily then drill down to user information then the FK would belong to the user table.

Another thing you need to complete here is whether the FK is mandatory or optional (Not Null or Nullable) since this would affect RI. What happens if I delete a user? Should the corresponding address go away?

Answer (score 0):

Here there is chance of getting more number of users in same address hence placing the Foreign key in address table would be my choice.

Comment: *same address* ... so multiple users with the same address could reference the same row in the address table.

Comment: But is it a business requirement to users to reference same address in db? Or is it really that every use should have their own editable address.